# How to add objects that use attributes from multiple info classes to an array list in main program?

Tags: java

I have a info class Vehicle that has multiple attributes and I have a Moped info class that extends the vehicle class. I need to create a main program that I can add multiple mopeds to an array list and then print them. Here is my attempt:
info class1:

---

```
package data;

public class Vehicle {
private float price;
private String color;
private int maximumSpeed;

public float getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(float price) {
    this.price = price;
}
public String getColor() {
    return color;
}
public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color= color;
}
public int getMaximumSpeed() {
    return maximumSpeed;
}
public void setMaximumSpeed(int maximumSpeed) {
    this.maximumSpeed = maximumSpeed;
}

public String toString() {
    return "Price: "+this.price+" Color: "+this.color+" Maximum speed: "+this.maximumSpeed;
    
}

}
```

---

Info class2:

```
package data;

public class Moped extends Vehicle{
private String Brand;
private String type;

public String getBrand() {
    return brand;
}
public void setBrand(String brand) {
    this.brand= brand;
}
public String getType() {
    return type;
}
public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}


public String toString() {
return "Brand: "+this.brand+" Type: "+this.type;

}

}
```

Main program:

```
package app;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import data.*;

public class ExtendsTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    ArrayList<Moped> list=new ArrayList<>();
    Moped mp=new Moped();
    askForMopedInfo(mp);
    lista.add(mp);
    
    printMoped(list);
}

private static void printMoped(ArrayList<Moped> list) {
    for (int i=0;i<list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
        
    }
    
}

private static void askForMopedInfo(Moped mp) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.print("Brand: ");
    String k = scanner.nextLine();
    mp.setBrad(k);
    
    System.out.print("Type: ");
    k = scanner.nextLine();
    mp.setType(k);
    
    System.out.print("Price: ");
    int k1 = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
    mp.setPrice(k1);
    
    System.out.print("Color: ");
    k = scanner.nextLine();
    mp.setColor(k);
    
    System.out.print("Maximum speed: ");
    k1 = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
    mp.setMaximumSpeed(k1);

}

}
```

When I run the program I get asked for:

```
Brand: 
Type: 
Price:
Color:
Maximum speed:
```

But the program only prints:

```
Brand: x Type: x
```

And I am still not sure how to add multiple mopeds to the array list. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you saying that the `askForMopedInfo()` method doesn't run and only asks the first two questions?

Comment: 1. The code has multiple typos such as `lista` and `Mopo` and does not compile. 2. To print output from parent class, call `super.toString()` in `Moped::toString`.  3. You added one moped to the list using `add` -- what is stopping you from using this method several times or in a loop?

Comment: The `askForMopedInfor()` works but the printing method `printMoped` only prints the brand and type. Also I'm trying to add multiple mopeds to the array list. Any suggestions on how to would be really helpful?

Comment: The typos are there because I missed them while translating the code to English while writing my request sorry for that. Would you kindly explain more about the second and third point you mentioned? How can I implement them to the code? I'm new to Java and programing in general-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update toString method of your Moped class, like this:

```
package data;
public class Moped extends Vehicle {
    /*
        other code
    */

    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() +" Brand: "+this.brand+" Type: "+this.type;
    }
}
```

to Add more mopeds to the array list, you can do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    ArrayList<Moped> list=new ArrayList<>();
    While(true){
       Moped mp=new Moped();
       askForMopedInfo(mp);
       list.add(mp);
       printMoped(list);
    }
  
}
```

Comment: Does `super.toString` allow printing from `String toString()` in the parent data package? And how can I add more mopeds to the array list?

Comment: yes, you can but make the attributes of the parent class (Vehicle) as protected and not private. I suggest you in my answer how you can add more mopeds to the array list. Please don't forget to accept my answer if it work.